# EF core 2.1 select/distinct

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, c#-6.0, ef-core-2.1

I'm using sql profiler to see sql generated by Ef core2.1,
this is my linq query :

```
var resulat = (from a in A
               join b in B equals a.level=b.level
               where ...
               select new M1 {AId = a.id}).Distinct();

(from r in resulat
 join c in C equals r.AId = c.AId
 select new M2 
 {
   CId = c.Id,
   level = _helper(c.level)
 }).Distinct();
```

**Sql generated:**

```
select t.AId,c.Id,c.level
from 
 (
    select distinct a.id 
    from A a
    inner join B b on a.level=b.level   
    where ...       
 ) as t
inner join C c on t.AId = c.AId
```

What i want as result is :

```
select distinct c.Id,c.level
from 
(
    select distinct a.id 
    from A a
    inner join B b on a.level=b.level   
    where ...       
) as t
inner join C c on t.AId = c.AId
```

I have tried also using select/distinct with result IQueryable, but the sql generated is the same.
what i missed in my linq query or what i have to add to have this sql query

Comment: T-SQL is not case sensitive - might that affect things?

Comment: Why do you care that it generated a SQL query different to the one you expected? This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: @mjwills the result is different, without distinct i have more than 10 000 rows with distinct i have 2000

Comment: This might be EFC bug. Have you checked if the query causes [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval)?

Comment: Also I can't check 2.1 now, but 2.2 seems to produce the desired SQL.

Comment: In most cases it's better, and possible, to avoid Distinct altogether. Here you could do that by `from a in A where a.Bees.Any() select ...`. Note that I assume the presence of a navigation property (which really should be there).

Comment: @GertArnold i deleted Distinct from **result** query then **t.AId** disappeared from my selection BUT EF Core can't add Distinct to my select, it seems for me that Distinct work only for select with one value not more -Model-

Comment: @IvanStoev UpVote for your comment [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) forbidden adding Distinct to query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what worked for me:

1. Delete *Distinct()* from **result** query, this avoid adding **t.AId** to my selection.
2. Delete a helper method from one of my selection fields performe adding Distinct() to final query.

This is my query after correction:

```
    var resulat = from a in A
                  join b in B equals a.level=b.level
                  where ...
                  select new M1 {AId = a.id};

    (from r in resulat
    join c in C equals r.AId = c.AId
    select new M2 
    {
      CId = c.Id
      level = c.level
    }).Distinct();
```

Many thanks for your comments, it really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always a fan of querying the data you want directly from the table (well, DbSet) that returns the data. The process looks a bit like these steps:

1. I want `C.Id` and `C.Level`
2. That's `context.Cs`.
3. *Which* `C`s do I want?
4. The ones that have a parent `A`, of which at least one `B` has the same 'level' as `A` and meets a couple of other criteria (the `where ...`).

That amounts to:

```
from c in context.Cs
where context.Bs.Any(b => b.level == c.A.level && <other criteria>)
select new { c.Id, c.Level }
```

If the `where ...` also contains filter criteria for `A` you can add predicates like `&& c.A == ...` to the `where`.

Note that I assume a navigation property `c.A` to be present, otherwise to be created, because `C` has `AId`.